# SQL Creating a Table with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need assistance in creating a table in SQL. I need some help adding some constraints. EMP_NUM should be a primary key and foreign key 2.  RTG_CODE should be a primary key and foreign key 1.

This is what I got so far:

```
 CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
 (
 EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY, 
 EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
 );

 COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate what RDBMS (database program) you are using.

Comment: So, what's wrong with what you have?  Are you not getting what you want?  Why not?

Comment: I need to make EMP_NUM  a FK in addition to it being a PK and RTG_CODE should also be a PK in addition to it being a FK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreign keys need to reference something.  Here is an example of syntax that might work for you:

```
 CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
 (
     EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
     EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (RTG_CODE) REFERENCES RTG(RTG_CODE)
 );
```

Comment: So could I make RTG_CODE referenced to EARNED_DATE?

Comment: @Chris . . . A foreign key should be referencing the primary key of a table.  And, it doesn't make sense to have a character column referencing a date column.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see is you aren't supplying the the table for the foreign key.  You can put this in on the same row.

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
 (
 EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RTG(RTG_CODE), 
 EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
 );

COMMIT;
```

Or have a named constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
 (
  EMP_NUM NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  RTG_CODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY, 
  EARNED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT fk_RTG_CODE FOREIGN KEY (RTG_CODE)
  REFERENCES RTG(RTG_CODE)
 );
COMMIT;
```